# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable simple

Tags: python, typeerror

```
import random

People = []

for x in range(0,3):
    name = input("Enter your name here:\n") 
    country = input("Here do you live:\n")
    age = input("How old are you:\n")
    person = (name, country, age)
    People.append(person)
    print(People)

for row in People(0,3):
    row = name,country,age
    print(name, "\t", country, "\t", age)
```

The error doesn't really make sense and every time I look for a solution, it doesn't seem relevant to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change: `for row in People(0, 3):` to `for row in People:`

I think the error message is pretty clear. Python `list` are not a function, and you're trying to call the `list`. `range` is a function that why you use `range(0, 3)`.

If you need your `for` to access only the first three elements of your `list` you need to use this: `People[0:3]`. You can also omit the zero if you want: `People[:3]`. This is called **splicing** and you can read more about that [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in this part:

```
for row in People(0,3):
```

By using `(` and `)` rather than `[` and `]` you're telling it that `People` is a function and you're calling it with the arguments `0` and `3`.

Your choices are to just say:

```
for row in People:
```

if you want to do every single row.  Or

```
for row in People[0:3]
```

if you want to just do some specific ones (which right now is all the rows).